# Uncompiled java class but still executes

Tags: java, compilation

I have following piece of code in one of my java program.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
}

    public static void printOutput(String[] arr){

        //Note: The semi colon is omitted intentionally.
        System.out.print("Hello Incomplete World")
}
```

When I build it I get a compilation error but still it generates a .class file. when I run the .class file, it gives an output of "Hello World".

How is this possible ? I always believed a .class file having unresolved compilation problems will never be an executable one. Can anyone provide some information on that ?

Comment: You are running a previously-compiled version of the class.

Answer (score 1):

What's probably happening here is that a successfully compiled class file already exists. When the Java compiler runs, it'll produce a `.class` file if it compiles a source file successfully, but it will not remove subsequent compilation fails.

Comment: Downvoted because there is no "probably" about it. The compiler won't accidentally produce a working class file if there was a syntax error in the source.

Comment: @AndyTurner Probably was not in reference to whether the compiler was to producing a file. It does not even appear in the same sentence as the explanation thereof. Probably was in reference to the example sequence of events that led to the issue.

Comment: Downvotes can't be removed unless you edit. Here's an upvote to make up for it, though.

Comment: Andy.. I just tried creating one fresh and faulty piece of code which shouldn't have compiled. Strangely, it did compile and produced the results.
However, if I try to do the same thing from command line in windows it does not generate the .class file at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming the compiler will clear out your old class files - it doesn't.

Check the modification date on your current .class file - you'll see that it's older than your compilation. That's because it was generated from working code, not from your current source file. If you delete this class file, then try to recompile, you'll see that a new class file is not created.

Answer (score 0):

The class file you are running is from a previous compilation. Compile your program again and look at the time the class file was previously modified.